# angular $http vs factory to call http request

Tags: angularjs

Can someone point out whythese two codes doesn't work the same way? `$http.post` request works fine and gives me the `response` back on the other hand using a factory to do the `post` request it gives me [object object] response but network payload shows the `username` and `password`.

html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="vm.userlogin.username">

<input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" ng-model="vm.userlogin.password">
```

straight from controller:

```
$http.post('/api/login/', vm.userlogin).success(function(response){
            localStorage.setItem('key', response);
            $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
            $location.path('/dashboard');
        }).error(function(error){
            console.log('err');
        });
```

using factory:

```
signupService.login(vm.userlogin.username, vm.userlogin.password)
            .then(function(response){
                console.log(response);
                localStorage.setItem('key', response);
                $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
                $location.path('/dashboard');
        });
```

login factory:

```
function _login(username, password){
        var data = {
            username: username,
            password: password
        };
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/login/',
            data: data
        });
    };
```

Comment: When you use `.then()` don't you need to use `response.data` to get the actual data?

Comment: what yes damn, that was a simple one :( thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`response` object in first `then()` of `$http` promise is not the same as in `success()`. Your data is in  the `data` property of it

Try using `response.data`